# eliminate +0000 from retrieved date from FireStore and display in Text in ForEach loop

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

How to get just date and time without +0000 from this date I retrieved from FireStore? if this is possible, can i do all process inside a Text inside ForEach?

```
return MyBook(bookDate: sub["bookDate"] as? String ?? "")
```

what i got "2022-07-11 22:31:00 +0000"

what i wanted "2022-07-11 22:31:00"

Comment: You should look into storing Custom Objects with Firestore, you are missing the core of what those zeros mean. It is the UTC timezone, when you save that date Swift is likely changing the from the user's local time to UTC if you just remove the zeros and display the string without them then the time will likely not be correct.

Comment: i never face this problem yet but this is very nice information for me. i think i need to check up on this type of data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to this post/answer:

[swiftui datepicker how to display from firebase database date and time without milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694311/swiftui-datepicker-how-to-display-from-firebase-database-date-and-time-without-m/72694450#72694450)

You can use prefix for this case if it's a fixed formatted date:

```
date.prefix(19)
//after: "2022-07-11 22:31:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is standard date form in GMT, so suffix would be rather always the same, so you can use something like (if conversation to local zone is not needed)

```
"2022-07-11 22:31:00 +0000"
   .components(separatedBy: " ")
   .dropLast()
   .joined(separator: " ")
```